Laravel 11 is returning 419 page expired
Im using Laravel 11 with Postman to test my API. im planning to use VueJS later.
I created a Authentication Controller, and im using MySQL database, I also migrated everything (Laravel 11 migrations)
Now when I send a request to my route which is /register from postman I get 419 page expired.
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;


  return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
         web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
         api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
         commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
         health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {

    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

})->create();

web.php
Route::post('/register', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'login']);
also I would like to mention that i send a pre-request to /sanctum/csrf-cookie first.
pm.sendRequest({
   url: "http://localhost:9000/sanctum/csrf-cookie",
   method: "GET"
}, function(error, response) {
   if (!error) {
    const xsrfToken = pm.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
    pm.collectionVariables.set("xsrf-cookie", xsrfToken);
  }
});


I found this solution and it's work for me Sanctum API: 419 CSRF token mismatch with laradock

This question is similar to: Sanctum API: 419 CSRF token mismatch with laradock. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Capture the CSRF token from
Route::get('/token', function (Request $request) {
    $token = $request->session()->token();
    $token = csrf_token();
    return $token;
});

Then insert that token into the header:
X-CSRF-TOKEN: YOUR_CSRF_TOKEN_VALUE

Then send the POST API...
Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf
